# Getting Vimeo thumbnail images using php is unbelievably slow

Tags: php, thumbnails, vimeo

I'm using this php code to get the thumbnail images of Vimeo videos.

```
while($row = $database->fetch_array($result))
{
$url = $row["link"];
sscanf(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH), '/%d', $video_id);
$hash = unserialize(file_get_contents("http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/$video_id.php"));
$image = $hash[0]['thumbnail_small'];  
echo "<img class='vimeo_video' video='$video_id' src=$image>";
}
```

It fetches the images, but it takes at least 30 seconds to load the page.
Is it something to do with Vimeo's servers or my code?

Comment: Do you have any debugging tools? It would be really helpful to step through each line to see where the slowness creeps in.

Comment: The simple api url you provided loads quickly for me, but if you want to find the actual source of the issue you should do some profiling. For easy profiling you can just store microtime (http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) in a variable.